# $watch versus custom setter method

Tags: angularjs

Inside a directive with isolate scope, I want to call a method each time one of it's scope vars changes. Let's call this `methodX()`.

Assignments to this var are only applied from code inside the link function, never from anywhere else.

In this particular case, would you say using a custom setter method for this scope var and calling `methodX()` inside this setter is better than using a `$watch` on scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is probably a bit context-dependent, but for sure `custom setter` is more efficient, as `$watch` is executed at each `digest` cycle.

Comment: Thanks, Artur. [extra chars]